# event PageIndexChanging wasn't handled

Tags: events, gridview, page-index-changed

I'm getting "The GridView 'grdFiles' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled." even if I've added the event handler:

```
protected void grdFiles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GetFiles();
        grdFiles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdFiles.DataBind();

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question actually? more specific please

Comment: @ling.s I'm getting this error even I've handeled this event. Question is why? How can I solve that?

Comment: What error? have you mentioned

Comment: @ling.s I'm getting THE ERROR: "The GridView 'grdFiles' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You need to declare a method on your code behind that handles the PageIndexChanging event.

```
protected void grdFiles_PageIndexChanging (object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs  e)
{
grdFiles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
bindGridView()
}
```

the method bindGridView() is

```
private void bindGridView()
{
 grdFiles.DataSource=.....;
 grdFiles.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Where is the diference with that and the code I wrote? Also, I have tried to redefine datasource and reBind the grid within the event handler. Didn't work.

Comment: I already have method GetFiles() that binds data just fine on the first page. The problem occures when I change the page on the gridView. Then I get the message that event wasnt handled (even that it should be). Is there something I'm missing in Your answer?

Comment: If you have set a gridviews AllowPaging attribute to “true”

Comment: Alos, If you set AllowPaging="true" or AllowSorting="true" on a GridView control without using a DataSourceControl DataSource (i.e. SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource), you will run into this kind of error

Comment: Thank You for Your effort. That link didn't solve my problem on the spot but guided me to a solution. Problem solved and I'll give You "Thumbs up"!